# Using Rails.cache in a Rufus Scheduler job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, scheduler, rufus-scheduler

i have trouble with using the Rails.cache in a scheduler job.  The job is scheduled properly and executes model logic without a problem until i use the Rail.cache.  No information can be written nor read via the cache; my writes do not fail but when i read the cache i get a 'nil' return.  Can anyone help me figure out what is the problem?

config/initializers/task_scheduler.rb

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler::singleton

scheduler.interval('10s') do

  begin
    Rails.cache.write('city', "Duckburgh")
    stats = Rails.cache.read('city')
    ApplicationController.helpers.write_log("Rufus Scheduler", "Job Completed", stats)
  end

end
```

I am using [Rails MemoryStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemoryStore.html) with Puma in clustered mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "No information can be written nor read via the cache."? It's ambiguous.

Comment: i mean that whatever i write to the cache is not actually written.  the reads always return nil.  so any code i call which relies on reading information from the cache fails.    i use :memory_store as my cache store.

Comment: Please update your question to indicate that your using the http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemoryStore.html and also to indicate what server you're running on (passenger, unicorn, puma) and with what mode/options you're running that server. Also indicate what the write_log calls you have yield ("Duckburgh" or nil?).

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Rails 5.1.2 from Rails 4 the problem was fixed.  Given the amount of changes in gems and settings in the config files, i am not sure which of these changes solved my issue.